# JHipster configure maven wrapper proxy

Tags: maven, https, proxy, jhipster

According to https://jhipster.github.io/configuring-a-corporate-proxy/ I have set up my proxy settings in /.m2/settings.xml like this :

```
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myId</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>myDomain\myUsername</username>
      <password>myPassword</password>
      <host>myHost</host>
      <port>myPort</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

But somehow it is not working when I'm trying to mvnw the project, it's giving me :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I managed to get it work while passing below parameters to MAVEN_OPTS but I would like to do so with settings.xml file only.

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.proxyHost=myHost -Dhttps.proxyPort=myPort -Dhttps.proxyUser=myDomain\myUsername -Dhttps.proxyPassword=myPassword
```

Anyone can help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it normal that you set http in your settings.xml while in MAVEN_OPTS you use https?

Comment: Maven is supposed to handle https with http. Anyway I tried to put https, same error.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It seems Maven Wrapper does not use the proxy variables from Maven settings. The [Downloader](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper/blob/d89e40a2f5dc67fc75603a213b945de2a5ac0b14/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/wrapper/DefaultDownloader.java) does not configure any proxy, so this means Java system properties must be used. For authentication,  it just looks for the system property `http.proxyUser` and [uses it](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper/blob/d89e40a2f5dc67fc75603a213b945de2a5ac0b14/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/wrapper/DefaultDownloader.java#L111).

Setting the MAVEN_OPTS (as you mentioned and also [here](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/maven-wrapper-example#proxy-server-configuration)) works:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080"
```

or

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080"
```

The mvnw script also pulls in a file `.mvn/jvm.config` from the project path which can include these properties:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=host 
-Dhttp.proxyPort=port 
-Dhttps.proxyHost=host 
-Dhttps.proxyPort=port 
-Dhttp.proxyUser=username 
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=password
```

I've opened a pull request ([#446](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster.github.io/pull/446)) to add this info to the JHipster documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much! The jvm.config file solved it for me.

Comment: Official doc now mentions it at https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-a-corporate-proxy/

Comment: The quote is needed for the value, should be **export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080"**