# mvn not using my file jvm.config for configuring my proxy

Tags: jhipster

I come here to ask you a question about the proxy configuration. 
My problem is that the executable file ".\mvnw" does not take into account my file ./mvn/jvm.config 
I am using vs code 
Does anyone have an idea about this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JHipster configure maven wrapper proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187743/jhipster-configure-maven-wrapper-proxy)

Comment: "./mvn/jvm.config" should be ".mvn/jvm.config"  See official doc https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-a-corporate-proxy/